# remove duplicate record from two table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I want to remove duplicate record below is my queries:

```
WITH Records as
(SELECT   intDiamondId, txtStockNo as txtStockNo, tblMstRapVendors.txtRapID, txtRealStockNo as txtRealStockNo1, txtShape, 
          fltCarat, txtCut, txtColor,  txtClarity, fltPrice, fltRapPrice, fltRapPercentage, txtCertificate, 
          fltDepth, fltTable, txtGirdle, txtCulet,  txtPolish, txtSymmetry, txtFluorescence, fltCrown, fltPavilion, 
          txtMeasurements,txtCertificateNo, flgApproved, flgSold, txtRapCode ,dtDateModified,txtUpdatedBy,txtcomments,
          ISNULL(tblMstDiamonds.isActualImage,0) as isActualImage, ISNULL(flgblueprint,0) as  flgblueprint, ISNULL(flgPerfect,0) as flgPerfect, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dtDateModified DESC) AS 'RowNumber'
FROM      tblMstDiamonds WITH(NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN tblMstRapVendors WITH(NOLOCK) ON tblMstRapVendors.txtRapVendorCode = tblMstDiamonds.txtOwner 
WHERE     intDiamondid IN (6855065) AND txtRealStockNo IN ('2186043908','2186043908') )

SELECT  * FROM Records WHERE (RowNumber BETWEEN(1) AND 26 - 1)
```

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does your database content look like? What have you tried yourself?

Answer (score 0):

In this if you have any primary key? Or any unique field? If yes then use `DISTINCT`.

In a table, a column may contain many duplicate values; and sometimes you only want to list the different (distinct) values.

The `DISTINCT` keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: i know but in my query distinct now wrok beacuse i am used group by

Comment: where u have added group by?